# Using webcam in desktop along with WinRT API's MediaCopy Class

Tags: wpf, webcam, desktop-application

I am trying to use webcam from desktop WPF application with WinRT API's MediaCopy class and CaptureElement and not succeeded, i came to know that, for desktop application we can't use CaptureElement. Is there any other way to achieve the same without leaving the MediaCopy class?

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: This might be helpful to you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx